# JavaFX change scene after click on button

Tags: java, javafx

I have a java desktop app that check if a new version of certain files is available and ask the user to download it. When the user click yes the question remains visible and I wan't to show a message like "downloading, please wait". But I don't know how do that...

```
private void updateAvailable(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("A new version is available. Update?");
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    Label label = new Label(stage.getTitle());
    label.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 25");
    Button yesButton = new Button("YES");
    Button noButton = new Button("NO");

    HBox buttons = new HBox(10, yesButton, noButton);
    buttons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    yesButton.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");
    yesButton.setOnAction(event -> downloadFiles());

    noButton.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");
    noButton.setOnAction(event -> executeApp());

    VBox root = new VBox(label, buttons);
    root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    root.setSpacing(20);
    root.setPadding(new Insets(25));
    root.setStyle("-fx-border-color: lightblue");

    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.show();
}


private void downloadFiles(){
    updaterService.backupCurrentVersion();
    updaterService.downloadNewestVersion();
}
```

I tried to create a new scene inside the download method (before the download starts) and hide the current, but didn't work, the new scene only blinks when the download is finished.

What would be the best aproach to do this? I think I'm missunderstanding how scenes works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an Information Dialog for this job. The JavaFX offers the `Alert` class for this purpose. Something like below may be helpful in your case:

```
displayMessage(){
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
    alert.setTitle("Information Dialog");
    alert.setHeaderText(null);
    alert.setContentText("Downloading, please wait");

    alert.showAndWait();
}
```

The above method could be included in the download button handler.

You can find more information regarding the `Alert` class in [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/toc.htm).
The above code can be included

Comment: That dialog remains opened until user accept, and if not accept it, the download isn't start.

Comment: This is not an issue. You can close this dialog after a couple of seconds in order to start the download.

Comment: I know that behavior is correct, but isn't works for my purpose, I need to do easy for my users, that dialog will confuse them, they are non technical people.
I just want to inform them about something is happening, please, sit and wait

Comment: If so then you can use a Progress Dialog in order to inform users that they have to wait until the download is completed. This can be done by using the `ProgressDialog` class. Read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ProgressBar.html) documentation for more information.

Comment: I been researching about ProgressDialog and ProgressBar and I found this and it works for me. Solution: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/ProgressBarandBackgroundProcesses.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage; 

public class Main extends Application {

    Stage window;
    Button button;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("thenewboston");
        button = new Button("Click Me");

        button.setOnAction(e -> AlertBox.display("Title of Window", Downloading..."));

        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.getChildren().add(button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 250);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }


}
```

When you click the button it will display a new scene with the message that you want to show.I did it with the Alert class.

Comment: What is `AlertBox`? You're not importing it, and it's not part of Java or JavaFX. This code doesn't compile. Did you write your own `AlertBox` class? If so, you need to include that code here.